# Get username and email on setpassword form

Tags: users

I am looking to make use of the users first name as well as their email address on setpassword page.

I am not seeing any way to grab those fields unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Craft currently doesn't expose that user info to the setpassword template.

You could write a plugin that mimicked that portion of Craft's [UsersController](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController) except returns the [UserModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/UserModel) (or part of it) to the template and/or make a [feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues) to expose more of info to that template.

---